# Close subview when the parent view is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have `parentView` and  subView `childView`.
`childView` is positioned in the middle of my `parentView` and is about half it's size.

I want to close `childView` when user tap on the `parentView`.

My code as follows creates a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the `parentView` once the `childView` is open.

My problem is that the tap event is triggered when the user touches any view, not just the `parentView`.

Thus, I was wondering how can I just make the event happen if  ONLY the parentView is touched or any other possible to close the sub view if the parent is touched.

```
- (IBAction)selectRoutine:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

    createRoutinePopupViewController* popupController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createRoutinePopupView"];

    popupController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
    _ass = popupController;
    //Tell the operating system the CreateRoutine view controller
    //is becoming a child:
    [self addChildViewController:popupController];

    //add the target frame to self's view:
    [self.view addSubview:popupController.view];

    //Tell the operating system the view controller has moved:
    [popupController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
-(void) handleSingleTap: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"TEST STRING");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate , implement following method.

it will check the touched view.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if( [touch view] != popupController.view)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: it says objView is undefined?

Comment: obviously it shoud say because you need to replace it by your parent view's object

Comment: hope you added <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in header file and also assigned the singleTap.delegate = self;

Comment: I did that and it never returns yes. I placed that code in the parentView file. tried selecting the parent and the child view, but always returns no

Comment: I added the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate